# How can I install gPhoto2 package on my PHP Server using MAMP

Tags: php, server, mamp, libgphoto2

I seek to install package gphoto2 in my PHP server (MAMP). 
I have already install gphoto on my computer and it work but I want to integrate gphoto on my php website 
Actually i try this:

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('wp-content/themes/barberry/script.sh 2>&1');
          echo "<pre>";
          var_dump($output);
          echo "</pre>";
?>
```

And i have this as return :
`wp-content/themes/barberry/script.sh: line 6: gphoto2: command not found`

I have also installed brew in my MacOS but i can't install gphoto2 on MAMP.
Thanks You !

Comment: What did you find out so far? What did you try?

Comment: I have updated my post thanks

Comment: nobody can help me ?

Comment: what in your script.sh, show it.